# How to transfer javascript data between websites?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i simply want to transfer a javascript array from one page to another javascript array on another page within the same domain. Php's get does not work because the user should not see the data and i don't know whether/how this could be done with post.
How would you solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the page on the same domain?

Comment: yes they are both on the same domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is trivially easy to do. The best way is to use `localStorage`, which is essentially cookies for the 21st century.

So on the first page:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(yourdata));
```

And on the second page:

```
var yourdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

You could use `sessionStorage` if you only need the data to work for the current browser session.

If you need to support older browsers, there are various shims that will add in the functionality. [This one](https://gist.github.com/remy/350433) looks quite good to me.

Comment: I haven't even thought of localStorage for this cause but i really like the idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Not a big deal, but you might want to suggest using `setItem` and `getItem` instead of accessing properties on the `localStorage` object directly. The main reason **I** suggest it is because when polyfills are used, this method usually isn't implemented/possible...while the methods are standard and will *always* work. Also, MDN "recommends" using these methods instead of property access, if that's any consolation

Comment: @Ian That's very useful, thanks. I have changed the code. it's a pity MDN's `localStorage` documentation is so dire: I never noticed that recommendation.

Comment: @lonesomeday Yeah, the way `localStorage` is implemented in polyfills, it wouldn't make sense for property getters/setters to work. I agree though, I don't like how the documentation on MDN is all on one page, and I just feel it isn't very good overall. But yeah, I randomly saw the recommendation because I thought someone had to agree to with me :)

Answer (score 2):

This would be cross-site scripting (XSS), which cannot be done reliably with JS.

If the pages are on the same domain, you can use PHP [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to keep data related to the user.

Comment: I should probably metion that the two pages belong to the same domain.
Does this change anything?

Comment: This can done be reliably with a JSONP ajax request because it does not violate the Same Origin Policy because script tags are allowed to reference resources outside of the domain.

Comment: The session solution also seems pretty good but I think I'll just go with localStorage for now.

thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to store this array in cookie using js. After receiving this array from cookie you can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jquery you can do something like this

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Comment: AJAX does not act like a normal link.

Comment: That was my first attempt but i need to open the page not only send the data.

Comment: This is a valid answer, if you bind the link to a function that fires off this ajax request before doing default behavior, then the goal is accomplished.

Answer (score -1):

If pages of same domain:

You need to post  `data` to the other page using a `form / AJAX`.

If Not , With JS you **cannot**

You need a `server` side code/process to handle data like that.